# Capitalize List of Figures and Tables Headings

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization

I am generating a list of tables and a list of figures in my thesis using \listoffigues and \listoftables commands, respectively. However, the titles of the lists turn out to be regular sentence cases. I would like to have an all-caps heading for the list of figures like LIST OF FIGURES. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Sadly, reliable psychics are not known to hang around this site. Unless you start providing usable information about your document setup, starting with which document class you employ, chances that anyone will be able to provide reliable solution ideas are rather slim.

Comment: Some document classes refer to these as `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename`.  To make them uppercase, the easiest method is brute force: `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}`.  However, since these command names aren't used in all document classes, unless we know which one you are using, we can't do better than guess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks. \renew command worked and solved my issue. I am using the article class.

Answer (score 1):

Since `article` has been identified as the document class in use, we know that the command names for the lists of figures and tables are `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename`.  Not all classes use these command names, but we know that the basic LaTeX classes (`article`, `book` and `report`) do; the corresponding AMS classes do as well, but for other classes, it's a good idea to check.  (In other words, if you are asking how to do this, potential helpers need to know the document class being used, and whether or not a package modifying the TOC is in use as well.)

The easiest (and probably most reliable) way to put these in all capitals is by brute force: `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}`, etc.